# What is wrong with this SQL query? All I want is counts by affiliation

Tags: sql, case, grouping

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COUNT([app_num]) AS APPS,
    CASE 
        WHEN [adm_td_rel_code] = 'NB' THEN 'NEW_TO_BANK' 
        ELSE 'BANK_AFFILIATE'
    END AS AFFILIATION
FROM 
    [USB_Repository].[dbo].[APP_ANALYSIS] 
WHERE 
    decsn_dt BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND  '2022-12-31'
GROUP BY 
    [app_num], [adm_td_rel_code]
```

I tried all that I can figure out

Comment: Don't forget to add a tag for the dbms you're using. (Perhaps <sql-server>?)

Answer (score 1):

A `GROUP BY` clause defines the granularity of the result set you are returning. In your case you want the granularity to be `AFFILIATION`; therefore, that should be the only column in your `GROUP BY` clause.

Also, the `DISTINCT` is redundant/superfluous in this case as the `GROUP BY` forces distinctness of the result set.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT([app_num]) AS APPS,
    CASE 
        WHEN [adm_td_rel_code] = 'NB' THEN 'NEW_TO_BANK' 
        ELSE 'BANK_AFFILIATE'
    END AS AFFILIATION
FROM 
    [USB_Repository].[dbo].[APP_ANALYSIS] 
WHERE 
    decsn_dt BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND  '2022-12-31'
GROUP BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN [adm_td_rel_code] = 'NB' THEN 'NEW_TO_BANK' 
        ELSE 'BANK_AFFILIATE'
    END
```

Depending on which RDBMS you are using (you don't specify) you may be able to replace the `CASE` expression in the `GROUP BY` clause with the column alias `[AFFILIATION]`. If that syntax is supported, it won't make any difference to the output of the query and likely won't affect performance either, but it will make the query more readable.